# Ruby Koans class or module required

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following error in Ruby Koans:

AboutHashes#test_accessing_hashes_with_fetch has damaged your karma.

The Master says:
  You have not yet reached enlightenment.
  I sense frustration. Do not be afraid to ask for help.

The answers you seek...
  class or module required

Please meditate on the following code:
  /home/s/Downloads/github/rubykoans/about_hashes.rb:26:in `test_accessing_hashes_with_fetch'

The line in question is part of the following method:

```
def test_accessing_hashes_with_fetch
  hash = { :one => "uno" }
  assert_equal "uno", hash.fetch(:one)
  assert_raise(nil) do
    hash.fetch(:doesnt_exist)
  end
```

As you can see, it is asking for a class or module, so I am confused as this is not an error I've encountered before in the Koans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is on these lines:

```
assert_raise(nil) do
  hash.fetch(:doesnt_exist)
end
```

The `assert_raise` test macro expects as its argument a class of Exception. You provided nil.

To skip to the answer, calling fetch on a hash with a key that doesn't exist in the hash will `raise` a `KeyError` Exception. So the test should have this:

```
assert_raise(KeyError) do
  hash.fetch(:doesnt_exist)
end
```